# How do I add location biasing to Google Places Autocomplete: Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

I have a places autocomplete field that I'm using to have users give a location. The autocomplete form is working, but it is NOT biasing the location as I want. I have the following code:

```
function activatePlacesSearch() {
  var input = document.getElementById('project-location-input');
  var location = {lat: 53.2910591, lng: -6.1823276};
  var radius = 1000;
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, location, radius);
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function(e) {
      const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
      lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
      // draw the map
      document.getElementById('new-project-map-div').style.display = 'block'
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('new-project-map-div'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      fullscreenControl:false,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
    });

// Set marker position
  var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      draggable: false
    });


  map.setCenter(myMarker.position);
  myMarker.setMap(map);
  });

}
```

I know that you can query as follows and it works:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=20&location=53.2910591,-6.1823276&radius=5000&key=AIzaSyC8sJYstB5U0fi8UdiHHAlG4tHVDuX_e-o

I would like to accomplish this using my code, but I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: Your `Autocomplete` constructor is incorrect, it only takes two arguments: `Autocomplete(inputField[, opts])`. one of which ["opts"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions) is an object and is optional, per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#Autocomplete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use the [`AutocompleteOption.bounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions.bounds). If all you know is a location and a radius, you can create a circle and call `getBounds` on it (there is no documented way to bias the javascript autocomplete with a location and a radius).

```
var location = {lat: 53.2910591, lng: -6.1823276};
  var radius = 1000;
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: location,
    radius: radius
  });
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
    bounds: circle.getBounds()
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/y0ob6r41/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function activatePlacesSearch() {
  var input = document.getElementById('project-location-input');
  var location = {lat: 53.2910591, lng: -6.1823276};
  var radius = 1000;
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: location,
    radius: radius
  });
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {bounds: circle.getBounds()});
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function(e) {
      const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      console.log(place);
      lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
      lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
      // draw the map
      document.getElementById('new-project-map-div').style.display = 'block'
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('new-project-map-div'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      fullscreenControl:false,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
    });

// Set marker position
  var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      draggable: false
    });

  map.setCenter(myMarker.position);
  myMarker.setMap(map);
  });

}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#new-project-map-div {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
  <div id="pac-container">
    <input id="project-location-input" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="new-project-map-div"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=activatePlacesSearch"
        async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this section in their docs: [google places autocomplete location biasing](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete?utm_campaign=mdr-launch&utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers#location_biasing). You may be able to take advantage of the `strictbounds` and `components` params.

If that doesn't get you any closer to what you're trying to accomplish, post a link to a CodeSandbox with your example and I can help you figure it out.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Raz. I will post something to CodeSandbox asap. The strictbounds does an absolute restriction to within your boundary, whereas biasing simply prefers your boundary, but will return results outside of that boundary.

Comment: Components on the other hand limits you to a specific country/state etc. Again like strictbounds this is an absolute restriction as opposed to bias/preference that locationbias provides.

Comment: Hey Raz, here is a link to the CodeSandbox. You will need to put in your own API key in order to get it to work. You will need the Places API enabled on your account to use it. Cheers!

https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-grass-8ew2f?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0):

After doing some investigative work here's what I came up with.
It seems that unless you are displaying a map on the DOM (it can be positioned out of sight if you don't want to see it) then this doesn't work correctly.
Here's [an example I found on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raz2121c/h5u6j18q/)

//snippet

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 39.742347, lng: -104.941121}, //Denver, CO
    zoom: 12
  });
```

And [here's my CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cookies-07n5b) using your sandbox and some pointers from the example above.